# Discrepancy between two similar presto SQL queries

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have the following SQL queries that should written similar results wrt offset column, but dont.

Query 1:

```
SELECT visitor_id, array_agg(timestamp) as time, array_agg(offset) as offset_list 
from
(SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT visitor_id, timestamp,
cast(json_extract(uri_args, '$.offset') AS int) as offset


FROM table_t 
where year = 2023 and month = 1 and day = 27 and 

request_uri = '/home_page')
order by visitor_id, timestamp)
group by visitor_id 
order by cardinality(offset_list) desc
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT visitor_id ,array_agg(offset) as offset_list 
from
(SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT visitor_id, timestamp,
cast(json_extract(uri_args, '$.offset') AS int) as offset


FROM table_t 
where year = 2023 and month = 1 and day = 27 and 

request_uri = '/home_page')
order by visitor_id, timestamp)
group by visitor_id 
order by cardinality(offset_list) desc
```

Here uri_args is simply a json file which under the key 'offset' contains the value of the offset for the particular API response. This is from response log table of a server.

Although the two queries are similar and according to me ought to return the same values in the offset_list column i find the following discrepancy :

I will consider a particular visitor_id to convey it clearly, for a visitor_id ='12345' query i returns the following row in the offset_list col

```
[0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 10, 20, 32, 42, 0, 0, 20, 53, 77, 57, 0, 10, 20, 31, 10, 41, 0, 10, 41, 54, 77, 0, 10, 31, 41, 54, 10, 31, 54, 57, 77, 10, 20, 32, 0, 10, 21, 33, 44, 72, 52, 0, 10, 20, 31, 41]
```

and for query 2 the output is as follows :

```
[20, 32, 42, 0, 0, 20, 53, 77, 57, 0, 10, 20, 31, 10, 41, 0, 10, 41, 54, 77, 0, 10, 31, 41, 54, 10, 31, 54, 77, 57, 10, 20, 32, 0, 10, 21, 33, 44, 72, 52, 0, 10, 20, 31, 41, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 10]
```

I can observe the the two are circular permutations of each other but fail to see why this is happening. Please help me understand what the difference is the inner working of each query. The first reply suits the intent of my quest which is to capture the visitors journey on the homepage.

Comment: Didn't you try displaying the output of the subquery without the grouping to see if the issue with the order happens there already? BTW, I think you can remove the `SELECT * FROM ` subquery and simply include `order by visitor_id, timestamp` in the innermost one.

Comment: @Andrew ..i have removed the redundant subquery but the problem still persists

Comment: What about the first thing I said? If having an `order by` gives you varying results, it's probably because there are tied values and there are more things to order by.

Comment: @Andrew I have tried that as well, the result of the subquery before group by is perfect and displays the data as is in the first array but once the outermost query runs which has aggregate functions in it something seems to go wrong and i end up getting diff results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need your array elements deterministically ordered specify `order by` clause for aggregate function as mentioned in the [docs](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html)

> Some aggregate functions such as `array_agg()` produce different results depending on the order of input values. This ordering can be specified by writing an `ORDER BY` Clause within the aggregate function

```sql
SELECT visitor_id ,array_agg(offset order by timestamp) as offset_list 
-- ...
```